# fossology docker image fails to start

Tags: docker

Anyone get docker [fossology](https://hub.docker.com/r/fossology/fossology/)  images to start?  Figured I'd ask before trying to 'fix' latest and submit patch to fossology.

**Problems Found**

**lastest**

`sudo docker run -p 8081:8081 fossology/fossology`

`chmod: changing permissions of '/var/run/postgresql': Operation not permitted`

`psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fossy"
 FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fossy"`

**3.1.0rc1**

`sudo docker run -p 8081:8081 fossology/fossology`

`psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fossy"
 FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fossy"`

Comment: Have you considered alternative such as https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit ?

Comment: The project was terminated before I got much beyond this point.  So, alas not.

Comment: sure, If you ever have a similar problem (e.g. find out about the license and origin of code) just keep it in mind then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fixing your problem if started as user root

```
docker run -u root -p 8081:8081 fossology/fossology
```

but it gives an error starting scheduler (address alredy in use) and it connects to database as user postgres.

By supplying env. variable about db it gives the same error. If you run as

```
docker run -u root -e FOSSOLOGY_DB_PASSWORD=fossy -e FOSSOLOGY_DB_NAME=fossology -e FOSSOLOGY_DB_USER=fossy -p 8081:8081 fossology/fossology web
```

the connection to http://localhost:8081 give the message

> Could not connect to FOSSology database.

I'm sorry, I can't help further.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help.  I figure I might need to tweak it